# TortoiseSVN: Get only files that have changed (or are new) since a particular revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Using TortoiseSVN I'd like to get only files that have changed (new or have been updated) since a particular revision. I'd like to export the latest version of these files to a temp directory. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Open the log](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html) for the path that you want to perform this on.
2. Click on the "Show All" button in the lower left, then "Show Range", and change the range of revisions to start at your particular revision and end at HEAD:
   [image: Dialog showing start and end range selection]
3. Select all revisions in the log dialog (the list in the top pane). This combines all changes and shows all files in the lower pane.
4. Select all changed files (the list in the lower pane), and right-click on them and click "Export...":
   [image: Context menu shown for changed files]
5. Choose the folder to export the files to.

You can also get a jump start by performing steps 1 and 2 with this command instead (replace the start revision and path):

```
tortoiseproc.exe /command:log /startrev:1234 /endrev:HEAD /path:C:\your\path\here
```

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I need!